# How to shift prediction value into NaN input value using regression model using python

Tags: python, pandas, regression, nan, prediction

Assume I have Four inputs and I want to predict next 2hour value of first input value When I am trying to predict the value there is NaN is containing the first input column.

What I tried to skip the NaN value , I am trying to shift the earlier pred value into that input column. But it didn't work for me.

```
[ 120   30  40  50 
  110   20  10  20
  NaN   12  30  30
  120   50  60  70
  NaN   10  28  40]  inputs to the model
```

What I expected output
  when training the model

```
[ 120   30  40  50 = pred1 
  110   20  10  20 = pred2
  pred2 12  30  30 = pred3
  120   50  60  70 = pred4
  pred4 10  28  40 = pred5 ]
```

Now here when the training the model NaN values removed and earlier prediction value should have to move to that NaN value position.
I wrote the code for that but it didn't work for me. Here is my code:

```
model.reset_states()
pred= model.predict(x_test_n) 
pred_count=pred[0]
forecasts=[]
next_pred=[]
for col in range(len(x_test_n)-1):
print('Prediction %s: ' % str(pred))
next_pred_res = np.reshape(next_pred, (next_pred.shape[1], 1, next_pred.shape[0]))
# make predictions
forecastPredict = model.predict(next_pred_res, batch_size=1)
forecastPredictInv = scaler.inverse_transform(forecastPredict)
forecasts.append(forecastPredictInv)
next_pred = next_pred[1:]
next_pred = np.concatenate([next_pred, forecastPredict])

pred_count += 1
```

Can anyone help me to solve this error? I just want to shift the earlier prediction value with NaN value.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through each row, get predictions and fill the nans.  Something like below i.e

```
prev_preds = 0
preds = []

# For each row of the dataframe get the predictions. 
for _,row in df.iterrows(): 
   # Fill the missing values with previous prediction, initially it will be zero.  
   row = row.fillna(prev_preds)
   # Now get the prediction and store it in an array
   preds.append(model.predict([row.values]))
   # Update the previous prediction to new prediction by accessing last element of the predictions array. 
   prev_preds = preds[-1]

# Assign the predictions to a new column in dataframe
df['predictions'] = preds
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. I have a one question that instead of df If I want to put x_test_n, then in your code  which code that  I have to change in this code?

Comment: You can simply do `df = pd.DataFrame(x_test_n)`. The above code is more like pseudo code, if you can understand the logic, you can apply it to your data. Have added the comments for further clarification.

Comment: Hay I got an error while I am putting wrote this code df = pd.DataFrame(x_test_n)  "Must pass 2-d input"

Comment: What is the shape of `x_test_n`?

Comment: shape of x_test_n is (673,4,2)